# Long files transcribed twice (have two operations running) - bug

Tags: javascript, google-speech-api, apollo-server

it seems that any long audio (> 4 min) somehow makes an API to spawn two operations instead of one. Whatever I've been doing (using event emitter pattern or promises) it is always like that.

As a result my db have two transcription instead of one (I don't even understand how it could be keeping in mind that mongoose model breaks when second text hit the backend)

Please, help me solve this, I struggle with that issue about two months now.

[image: 2019-04-20_21-18-54]

Environment details

- OS: MacOS 10.14.4 (18E226)
- Node.js version: 11.2.0
- npm version:
- `@google-cloud/speech` version: 2.3.0

Steps to reproduce

Run code:

```
async function transcribe(gcsuri, progressCB) {
  const reducerforSingleAlternative = (obj, item, index, array) => {
    item.alternatives[0].words.map(word => obj.words.push(word));
    obj.confidence += item.alternatives[0].confidence;
    obj.transcript += item.alternatives[0].transcript;
    if (index === (array.length - 1)) {
      obj.confidence /= array.length;
    }
    return obj;
  };

  process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = process.env.SPEECH_KEY;
  const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech').v1p1beta1;
  const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
  const audio = {
    uri: gcsuri,
  };
  const request = {
    audio,
    config: {
      encoding: 'OGG_OPUS',
      sampleRateHertz: 24000,
      languageCode: 'ru',
      enableSpeakerDiarization: true,
      enableWordConfidence: true,
      maxAlternatives: 1,
      enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
    },
  };

  const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);

  operation.on('progress', (metadata, apiResponse) => {
    console.log('metadata', apiResponse);
    progressCB(metadata.progressPercent);
  });

  const [results] = await operation.promise();
  console.log('promise', typeof results, results);

  return results.results.reduce(reducerforSingleAlternative, { words: [], confidence: 0, transcript: '' });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my Apollo Server. Somehow it forced API to make two operations (maybe something connected with timeouts). I've tried pure Node example and everything's OK.